# Is there an effort to develop build-oriented file system with automatic change detection of files?

Tags: git, hash, build, filesystems, checksum

I recently started to use Git. 
One of the interesting features I discovered was the use of hashes to quickly detect changes.

On the other hand, I see that build tools (like make, ant, javac, etc.) tries to detect changes in source files by checking file's timestamp.

The problems in this approach are:

1. If you work on more than one
   machine, you have to make sure all
   clocks are in sync, otherwise, a
   new file may be considered
   unchanged because the other machine's clock gave it timestamp of the past relative to the build machine.
2. On a big project, you have to scan all files' timestamp in order to detect a change.

I wonder if someone has already taken the Git approach in order to deal with these issues:

1. Each file has a unique hash, depending on its content, not timestamp.
2. Each directory also has its hash, depending on the files in the directory and their hashes.
3. Even the simple change deeply inside the source tree causes the root directory to have a different hash due to the above rules

Such a mechanism could help making build tools much faster, because detecting a change in source tree is a simple operation of hash comparison. If the hash of source tree root directory has changed, it means that a change occurred deeper in the source tree, so continue to scan the tree recursively for changes - exactly as Git does to detect changes.

It doesn't necessarily mean that this source tree has to be managed by Git. 
My idea is that the file system would automatically provide file's hash code as one of its attributes / metadata, so the build tool could rely on this instead of on timestamp. And in addition, directory hash would automatically reflect the state of the file in it.

I already read a little bit about Sun's ZFS, but I am not sure it's a complete solution to make builds faster.

What do you think about this idea?
Is there already such file system?
Is there already such build tool?

Comment: I think the main problem is that the file system and build tools (or any other tools) must *both* support this functionality. And this condition can be met only on some "closed" platforms where one group develops both the filesystem and build tools.

Comment: I agree but as in all improvements: someone has to do the first step forward and the rest would join later. It's possible to add hash based file comparison to build tool as soon as the file system supports this.

Comment: I think at least make will have problems, since make does only rely on the filesystem timestamps to determine which targets must be rebuild. One would need a new make-like program which can handle checksums.

Comment: What you describe sounds a little like ClearCase's ClearMake build tool, which interacts with ClearCase's emulated filesystem.

Comment: @slowdog, what's your experience with ClearMake? Does this concept of detecting changes not by timestamp but by contents works?

Comment: @David, my exposure to ClearMake was brief and some years ago. As I recall it worked well, and the build tools knowledge of file content and of all file accesses had some useful side-effects like the ability to generate manifests ("Bill of Materials") of all the source file versions in a build for later reference, and to do ccache-like reuse of output files ("Wink-in") that had already been built from identical source content, even on a different machine. I don't specifically recall what the incremental build performance was like, but at least it wasn't memorably bad :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'll argue that what you're trying to solve is actually a non-issue:

The clock skew problem can be mostly avoided by using NTP.

Certainly it'd be nice to have clock skew issues eliminated entirely, but we can probably agree that throwing a fairly complex content-tracking system at the problem is overkill.

Regarding performance, scanning the entire tree tends to not be a problem in practice.  `stat` is ridiculously fast (so long as you're not on Windows) -- `ls -lR > /dev/null` over the entire Linux kernel tree (38k files) takes 350 ms on my system.

In fact, if stat'ing all your files is a problem, then your version control system will become slow, and that will be a much bigger problem than your build performance.  Every `git status` or `git diff`, for instance, stats *all* files in your working copy to check their mtimes, so you'd better hope that's fast.

So if you're looking to speed up `make`, don't look at the file system; it's most likely insignificant compared to whatever is actually eating up your build time.

Hope that eases your mind!

Comment: Just keep in mind that clock skew can only occur when packing files into ZIP / Jar in one machine and unzipping it on another machine. I recently found exactly such a scenario where timestamps where mistakenly in the future after unpack, and that caused the build script to behave differently and fail. Checksum could avoid this problem. I agree however that using timestamps it's easy to define "baseline". Using checksums you have only boolean "equals/different" flag.

Comment: That's because you're preserving dates, rather than letting the creation date be the date that the files are written.

Comment: You're right, archives are a problem.  I've edited my answer to reflect that NTP is really the only thing that'll stop these issues from happening.  But even on closed networks, you can easily install a local NTP server to keep clocks in sync, so I think this can be avoided in practice, no?  By the way, if you want to make automated processes robust, you could also use -m for tar or -DD for unzip to disable extracting mtimes (so they're set to "now").

Comment: @Arafangion: Yup.  Though that's the (unfortunate) default behavior of most archive utilities.  (I think you mean the *modification* date, by the way.)

Comment: Indeed, I did mean the modification date, although now that's pointed out, it's useful to note that the precise dates and their terminology is filesystem and operating system dependent.

Comment: the time it takes to check a timestamp isn't the issue. IDEs that decide to update the timestamp when the file hasn't actually changed (i.e. accidentally typed something in, backspace and accidentally save it causes a massive redundant rebuild because of dependencies). It's kind of nitpicky, but I think it has some merit.

Thankfully, it doesn't require a new filesystem: http://blog.jgc.org/2006/04/rebuilding-when-hash-has-changed-not.html