# Is there a filesystem that maintains an hashtree of file contents and directories?

Tags: filesystems, driver

Is there any filesystem that automatically maintains an hashtree of file contents and directories (something like git)?
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421202/is-there-an-effort-to-develop-build-oriented-file-system-with-automatic-change-d) question from 2010 but at the time it seams that there was none.
Does any one knows about the state of the art in filesystems?
Thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  (I imagine the problem is not specifically "I don't have a filesystem that uses hashes".)

Comment: I was just curious because I use syncthing to synchronize between my laptop and workstation and it takes forever in the "scanning" part and I assumed it was building some kind of hashtree. I don't think just checking timestaps would take that long. Meanwhile someone told me about Open ZFS